# What is the Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-3x-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this fraction to resemble $\frac{1}{(1 -x)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of handling this. For instance, you can use the familiar technique of long division of polynomials that you learned in high school, but writing the terms in *increasing* order of degree instead of decreasing. This is probably what Neda Kh did for that answer.

But did you know that
$$
\frac1{1-x-x^2}=1+x+2x^2+ 3x^3 + 5x^4 + 8x^5 +\cdots\,,
$$
the coefficients being the Fibonacci numbers? With this in mind, I figured that there might be a similar recursion for your coefficients. Indeed, if you set $G_0=1$, $G_1=3$, and $G_m=3G_{m-1}+G_{m-2}$, you’ll have the right recursion.

**EDIT**: At your request, I’ll go into in more detail. It turned out to be far more direct than I had guessed.

In fact, it all works out for the reciprocal of any polynomial, of form $f(x)=1-a_1x-a_2x^2-a_3x^3-\cdots-a_dx^d$. We’ll look for power series of the form $g(x)=1+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots=1+\sum_n^\infty c_nx^n$, and I’ll fill out all the coefficients of $g$ by writing $c_0=1$ and $c_r=0$ for all negative $r$. Then we need
$$
1=(1-a_1x-a_2x^2-\cdots-a_dx^d)\sum_{-\infty}^\infty c_nx^n\,.
$$
Look at this, and you realize that for $n\ge1$, to get the coefficient on the left of the equals sign to be $0$, you need $c_n-a_1c_{n-1}-a_2c_{n-2}-\cdots-a_dc_{n-d}=0$. Put the first term by itself,and get the recursion
$$
c_n=a_1c_{n-1}+\cdots+a_dc_{n-d}\,,
$$
where any $c_i$ with index negative is treated as zero. And there you are.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it's the most insightful one. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on how to use the formulae above to generate similar Fibonacci like series/power series expansions?

Comment: You’re right that there’s something much deeper going on. I’m not a combinatorialist, though, and I’ll bet that anyone in that field would be able to toss off an analysis of this that would be very satisfactory. However, I have a busy day today. I would like to get to this later, or tomorrow at the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write it using partial fractions.

Comment: But the chances are that OP doesn’t want to factor this.

Comment: I did write it as a partial fraction put after seeing it, I'm still not sure how to approach it. For the partial fraction I'm getting( 2/(sqrt(13)(2x + sqrt(13) + 3)) + 2/(sqrt(13)(-2x + sqrt(13) - 3)) So I guess my real question is that I don't see how that can be transformed into (1/1-x)

Comment: Each term can be written in the form $\dfrac{c}{1-bx}$

Comment: Yeah, but as with $1/(1-x-x^2)$, the reciprocal roots $b$ are quadratic irrationalities, and it doesn’t come out particularly esthetically pleasing (depending on your esthetics, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-3x-x^2}$ around zero $1+3x+10x^2+33x^3+109x^4+O(x^5)$

Comment: Giving an answer without any explanation or derivation is not helpful.

Comment: This answer is from mathematica software...should be accurate!

Comment: I'm sure the poster could have put the expression in Mathematica as well. That's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{1-\boxed{STUFF}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big( \boxed{STUFF} \big)^n
$$
holds as long as $\Big|\hspace{1mm} \boxed{STUFF}\hspace{1mm} \Big| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
to get
$\frac1{1-ax-bx^2}$:

We want
$1-ax-bx^2
=(1-ux)(1-vx)
$.
Assuming that we have it,
if

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{(1-ux)(1-vx)}
&=\frac{p}{1-ux}+\frac{q}{1-vx}\\
&=\frac{p(1-vx)+q(1-ux)}{(1-ux)(1-vx)}\\
&=\frac{p+q-x(pv+uq)}{(1-ux)(1-vx)}\\
\end{array}
$

so we want
$p+q=1$
(so $q = 1-p$)
and
$0
=pv+uq
=pv+u(1-p)
=u-p(u-v)
$
so
$p
=\frac{u}{u-v}
$
and
$q
=1-p
=1-\frac{u}{u-v}
=\frac{(u-v)-u}{u-v}
=\frac{-v}{u-v}
=\frac{v}{v-u}
$.

Note:
I am assuming here that $u \ne v$.
You can work out
what happens if $u = v$.

Then
$\frac1{1-ax-bx^2}
=\frac{p}{1-ux}+\frac{q}{1-vx}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (pu^n+qv^n)x^n
$.

The step omitted above
is to solve
$1-ax-bx^2
=(1-ux)(1-vx)
$
for $u$ and $v$.
But this is just
solving the quadratic equation
$1-ax-bx^2
=0
$
but for $\frac1{x}$,
not $x$.

To see this,
divide by $x^2$
to get
$\frac1{x^2}-\frac{a}{x}-b
=(\frac1{x}-u)(\frac1{x}-v)
$.
This gives
$\frac1{x}
=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}
$,
and one of these is $u$
and the other is $v$.

For the original problem,
$a=3$ and $b=1$,
so the roots are
$\frac1{x}
=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9+4}}{2}
=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}
$.
Setting
$u = \frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$
and
$v = \frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}$,
$u-v
=\sqrt{13}
$
and
$p
=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2\sqrt{13}}
=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{13}}+\frac12
$
and
$q
=\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{-2\sqrt{13}}
=-\frac{3}{2\sqrt{13}}+\frac12
$.